# Why do I need an HttpSession to get the ServletContext?

Tags: java, httpsession, servlets

In the Java Servlet API, the only way to get the `ServletContext` is through an instance of `HttpSession` ([Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getServletContext%28%29)).

What if I don't want to create a session and only need the servlet context? In other words, why is there no `getServletContext()` method in the `HttpServletRequest` class?

**EDIT**

I know I can get the `ServletContext` from the servlet itself, since it receives it during its initialization. However, I cannot get it from a `HttpServletRequest` alone, even though it's linked to a servlet. So what if I have a request, but no reference to any servlet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`getServletContext()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletContext%28%29) is part of `GenericServlet` which is the parent class for `HttpServlet` so you should be able to call it in your servlet implementation.

**Edit:**

`HttpServletRequest` inherits [`getServletContext()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServletContext%28%29) from `ServletRequest` since *servlet 3.0*, so it looks like you will have to pass a context along with the request and response objects if you have to use a version prior to 3.0.

Comment: That's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 3):

It's just that every entity working with requests (servers, filters, pages) has its own `getServletContext` (or `init()`)

Comment: +1, however, it's not always the case. Sometimes you only have a request, and the only way to the servlet context is throught the session.

Comment: @LaurentPireyn e.g., when you've passed the request in further layers otherwise unaware of Servlets API? It is possible, but in this case we end up with lost of questions: whether getting `ServletContext` is a good idea in the first place; shouldn't we just push context into attributes; shouldn't we reorganize our logic; etc...

Comment: I'm slipping into the "sour grapes" mode, sorry. Anyway, what is the real problem? The rationale I believe is to keep the number of methods reasonable: I'm more surprised that `getServletContext` did it into `HttpSession`.

Comment: I'm also surprised, hence my question. The request has direct access to the servlet context (not through the session) since Servlet 3 (credits go to rsp for mentioning that). So it was probably something they indeed forgot.

Answer (score 1):

Your servlet class has a getServletContext() method you don't need to go to the request.

This makes sense, the servlet itself has a context provided by the container, this is independent of any particular request.

Comment: That's not what the question is about.

Comment: @Laurent the original question didn't have the extra info that only the request was available.